# Why is the topology so bad on this mesh with quads?

Tags: mesh, topology, retopology, remesh

I am trying to model a Daihatsu Midget II for a video game as I found this car to be iconic and have a relatively simple shape without any complex lines. Despite using quad-gons the model with Shade Smooth and Edge Split applied seems to look distorted on the bending:
[image]

[image]

I know it's badly modeled but that shouldn't affect the topology this much.

I tried remeshing with modifiers and Blender add-ons but all of them completely distorted the mesh.

Of course every normal is facing the same direction.

Can I do anything to fix this or do I have to remodel from all over again?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is the red color from the _Face Orientation_ overlay? Then the normals are all facing in the same direction, but this direction is inside out. They should be blue. Apart from that, how does it look without the _Edge Split_ modifier? And have you set the object to _Shade Smooth_ or _Shade Auto Smooth_? Have you checked if there is any duplicate geometry? If there are other issues it's not easy to tell without checking the file. Just be aware that "all quads" is helpful but not a guarantee that everything looks perfect, especially with sharp turning edges etc.

Comment: Hi @GordonBrinkmann! No, this is actually the color I set for the material, the side we see on the picture is the visible side. Without edge split it looks like melted clay, I used Shade smooth without Auto smooth as it makes the situation even worse and the mesh becomes overly glossy. I used merge by distance multiple times but there weren't any vertices to remove. It's just weird to see that face that has the same angle next to it is fine but this one not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though your faces are square/rectangular, it doesn't necessarily mean they are quads - in the image below, the three yellow dots highlight edges coming across the "bottom" and terminating on the edge of an existing quad - this adds 3 vertices to the quad, making it an *n-gon* (face with more than 4 vertices - 7 in this case). The blue dots signify places where I suspect the vertical edges do not continue along the "bottom". Blender will often give shading errors where n-gons are present (especially near edges and on curved surfaces). To fix this, make sure your faces are proper quads by ensuring that edge loops continue all the way "around" without terminating suddenly in the middle of a (quad) face, or if it does (sometimes necessary), make sure that face is in the middle of a flat area, and well away from "edges" or curved areas.

[image: Edges]

Comment: Thank you this must be it!